Something "in between" \[ \] and begin-end-center
This question is perhaps stupid or rather a finicky question for finicky people.
I have noticed that in ambient like "enumerate" (but even in general) using \[ ... \] or \begin{center} \( ... \) \end{center} leads to a difference (relevant and annoying) in the spacing left after the command itself, before the next element.
In particular, there is more space left after a command written with \[ ... \] rather than the other way. It's a matter of 2-3 millimiters at most, but to me it's rather annoying.
The fact is that writing \begin{center} \( ... \) \end{center} every time is annoying too.
Is there some alternative solution, or am I doomed? :D

your question is rather unclear and has no example. \[ and \begin{center} are only very slightly related so there is no reason to expect the same spacing. \[ is a math display and vertical space is added based on math parameters such as \abovedisplayskip and \begin{center} is a one item list so vertical space is controlled by latex's list parameters such as \topsep. These parameters may or may not have similar values, depending on how they are set in the document class (you have given no indication of that either)

@DavidCarlisle You're right. I will provide details and examples later. Now I'm really asleep :/
